# Arduino UNO GPS module

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, gps

I am thinking about buying a gps module for Arduino UNO.

I would like to install it on a self-build RC-car which is also controlled by Arduino.
The problem is, I cannot install the gps module on the top of the car (on the surface), only the bottom and or/middle space is "free". 
My questions are:

1)Is there a module which can overcome a small layer of steel (max 2cm thick) and some plastic and still get a good signal?

2)It would be nice to be able to store the data into a memory card.

3)It would be a great plus to be able to gather data real-time through some kind of connection. Sadly I do not know how to do here. Is there some place where I can look up any of this?

Do you think that this http://www.adafruit.com/products/1272 is what I need?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Just break out the headers on the GPS module to make for connections to the UNO.

2) Add a SD expansion slot on top of the GPS Module and break out the pins for those as the required pins for those as well.

3) I am not sure what you are asking exactly, but it seems to me that you want to analyze the data real-time.  Get a network shield and make sure you can SSH into it through another computer.

Note: When I say "break out the pins", I am simply saying either solder on some extra headers, or wires.